# Can't get data of computed state from store - Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm learning Vue and have been struggling to get the data from a computed property. I am retrieving comments from the store and them processing through a function called `chunkify()` however I'm getting the following error.

[image]

Despite the comments being computed correctly.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Home.vue

```
export default {
    name: 'Home',
    computed: {
        comments() {
            return this.$store.state.comments
        },
    },
    methods: {
        init() {
            const comments = this.chunkify(this.comments, 3);
            comments[0] = this.chunkify(comments[0], 3);
            comments[1] = this.chunkify(comments[1], 3);
            comments[2] = this.chunkify(comments[2], 3);
            console.log(comments)
        },
        chunkify(a, n) {
            if (n < 2) 
                return [a];

            const len = a.length;
            const out = [];
            let i = 0;
            let size;

            if (len % n === 0) {
                size = Math.floor(len / n);
                while (i < len) {
                    out.push(a.slice(i, i += size));
                }
            } else {
                while (i < len) {
                    size = Math.ceil((len - i) / n--);
                    out.push(a.slice(i, i += size));
                }
            }
            return out;
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to do here. Your computed property just loads things from the store. This probably works fine. Your init method assigns something to a local variable and clearly does not end up in the log statement. Then again, it did nothing useful to begin with, since you discard the result. Add `debugger` above `const comments` and step through your code to see what ends up where and figure out where your code starts to differ from what you expect it to calculate.

Comment: My guess is that comments is undefined by the time the `<home/>` component is loaded. So, on `mounted()` `this.$store.state.comments` is `undefined`, but by the time you debug the component in the Vue debugger, the computed property returns the value of `comments`. If it's being loaded as an ajax request, you may have to watch the property and run `chunkify`, rather than try to chunkify on `mount`

Comment: @seebiscuit Thank you for taking the time to reply, I really appreciate it. You were right, if I wrapped `this.init()` in a `setTimeout()` it all worked fine. I added `watch: {
  comments() {
   return this.$store.state.comments
  }
 },` And now it seems to work properly, thank you again.

Comment: On further thought, the store should return undefined for `this.$store.state.comments`, since you probably defined it to some intial state, like `state: { comments: null }`. It's important that it be defined in state from the time you define the store so that you get the value of reactivity tracking. (Well, since, `watch` is working, I'm going to assume that you're defining `comments` to `undefined`. Am I right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I wrote in the comments, the OPs problem is that he's accessing a store property that is not available (probably waiting on an AJAX request to come in) when the component is mounted.

Instead of eagerly assuming the data is present when the component is mounted, I suggested that the store property be `watch`ed and `this.init()` called when the propery is loaded.

However, I think this may not be the right approach, since the `watch` method will be called every time the property changes, which is not semantic for the case of doing prep work on data. I can suggest two solutions that I think are more elegant.

#### 1. Trigger an event when the data is loaded

It's easy to set up a global messaging bus in Vue (see, for example, [this post](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/)).

Assuming that the property is being loaded in a Vuex action,the flow would be similar to:

```
{
  ...
  actions: {
    async comments() {
      try {
        await loadComments()

        EventBus.trigger("comments:load:success")
      } catch (e) {
        EventBus.trigger("comments:load:error", e)
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

You can gripe a bit about reactivity and events going agains the reactive philosophy. But this may be an example of a case where events are just more semantic.

### 2. The reactive approach

I try to keep computation outside of my views. Instead of defining `chunkify` inside your component, you can instead tie that in to your store.

So, say that I have a JavaScrip module called `store` that exports the Vuex store. I would define `chunkify` as a named function in that module

```
function chunkify (a, n) {
   ...
}
```

(This can be defined at the bottom of the JS module, for readability, thanks to [function hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function).)

Then, in your store definition,

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: { ... },
  ...
  getters: {
    chunkedComments (state) {
      return function (chunks) {
        if (state.comments)
          return chunkify(state.comments, chunks);

        return state.comments
      }
    }
  }
  ...
})
```

In your component, the computed prop would now be

```
computed: {
  comments() {
    return this.$store.getters.chunkedComments(3);
  },
}
```

Then the update cascase will flow from the `getter`, which will update when `comments` are retrieved, which will update the component's `computed` prop, which will update the ui.

Answer (score 0):

Use getters, merge chuckify and init function inside the getter.And for computed comment function will return this.$store.getters.YOURFUNC (merge of chuckify and init function). do not add anything inside mounted.